# How to insert rows in middle of the xlsx file by using win32 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsx, win32com

- I need to insert empty rows in the middle of the xlsx file by using python win32.

How can I insert that rows? Can you please help me.

I tried `openpyxl`, `xlsxwriter and some other modules. It is working fine with that modules. But my template format is changing if I use those modules. So I need to write the same feature in win32.

Comment: Did you try having a look at [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) library for python?

Comment: Does the answer helped ??

Answer (score 2):

You can use openpyxl package as below:

```
import openpyxl

file = "sample.xlsx"
complte_xl= openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
sheet = complte_xl.worksheets[0] ## Opening 1st sheet
sheet.insert_rows(10,5) ## Insert rows is the function to add rows which says add 5 rows after 10 rows. Just change value of 10 and 5 acc. to your needs
```

Also, if you are not aware where or the length of the sheet always changes do below to find the number of rows:

```
row_count = sheet.max_row
```

Then Divide by  `row_count by 2`  or `(row_count + 1) /2` taking care whether it is even or odd to get middle of the sheet.

Comment: @srikanth: Does this solved your problem?

Comment: That is working fine. But if I use openpyxl my template format automatically changed. 
But in win32 the template format is not changed at all. So I need to write the code in win32.